# solr/lucene: possible to add term vectors after indexing?

Tags: solr, lucene, mahout

I inherited a lucene index and I'd love to point Mahout at it, but the initial configuration didn't call for any of the content fields to have termVectors associated with them.

is it possible (maybe by scripting Luke?) to add termvector information after documents have been indexed?

Comment: It is almost certainly impossible. Entries in Lucene index are read-only. But maybe you could still get to your goal in some roundabout way, like rebuilding the index based on the information in the existing index.